# Unique constraint, only when field value is in the future

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

For years I've designed most of my tables to have a DeactivatedDate field.  I like this method because it allows me to see when a record was deactivated, and it serves a double-purpose when I have a table that has its history recorded via a trigger (serves as an audit deactivated date).

The problem I'm now facing - is it possible to add a constraint that enforces some sort of uniqueness ONLY when a record is active?  I suppose this could be done in a trigger, but I really try to avoid them.  The record is considered active if `DeactivatedDate is null or DeactivatedDate > getdate()`.

The is null check is easy - this SQL works well:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.PersonHun ADD 
    IsActive AS CASE WHEN DeactivatedDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX uix_PersonHun_RecordNum
    ON PersonHun(RecordNum, OwnedByDataProvider, IsActive)
    WHERE RecordNum IS NOT NULL
GO
```

However, as soon as I add the condition to check getdate() to the computed field, I get the following error:

> Msg 2729, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 Column 'IsActive' in table
>   'PersonHun' cannot be used in an index or statistics or as a partition
>   key because it is non-deterministic.

The code that generates the error is:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.PersonHun ADD 
    IsActive AS CASE WHEN DeactivatedDate IS NULL 
        OR DeactivatedDate > GETDATE() -- This line here is the culprit
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
GO

-- Error occurs when creating the INDEX:
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX uix_PersonHun_RecordNum
    ON PersonHun(RecordNum, OwnedByDataProvider, IsActive)
    WHERE RecordNum IS NOT NULL 
GO
```

So I guess my question is: is there a better way than using a trigger to enforce some sort of rolling unique constraint, based on `getdate()`?

UPDATE: Thank you guys for your comments, but I think it's getting a little off-topic.

I may not have emphasized the importance of the unique constraint on a date field in the future.  The "IsActive" computed field in my example is not something I need (or even want) - it was just one attempt at making a uniquely constrained condition, only on future dates.

I don't want to change the schema of this table in anyway that would impact an external process.  The DeactivatedDate field has been well established in this table for years and I don't want to change that.  I'm thinking I'll need to resort to a trigger.

Comment: Why not just have the IsActive as an actual boolean/bit field instead of making it dependant on whether or not some other field has value? It's usually considered bad practice to interpret the unknown value (NULL) as another factor because you really do not know whether NULL is not set or set intentional (well, of course you might in your example, but generally speaking - because NULL is "UNKNOWN"). So if it was me, I'd make IsActive an actual real column, and still keep deactivate date for historical/logging purpose.

Comment: There's no way to enforce this in a declarative fashion. Humans can easily deduce what's going on but SQL Server would probably (if it were to support this) have to re-check every row in the table whenever `GETDATE()` changes (so, 300 times a second)

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  Until now, I've never ran into any shortcomings from doing it this way.  I prefer having the DeactivatedDate because it allows me to schedule a records removal at a future time, without running a job.  I don't agree that NULL represents unknown, it should represent nothing, which is correct for DeactivatedDate if it's active.  I think there are pros and cons to both methods.  I was just trying to do this with minimal impact to existing queries, this table has tons of data and lots of queries hitting it.

Comment: Why not you make that column like this- alter table dbo.PersonHun add isActive bit and then use update statement to set its values like this - update dbo.PersonHun set isactive = 1
where deactivatedDate is null or deactivatedDate>getdate() and then create your index. This way your index will prevent you from entering repeated columns in the future as well.

Comment: That seems like a lot of work for a table that is constantly updated from many sources.  Frankly I don't even want IsActive at all.  I was just trying to set a unique constraint and I thought a computed field would do what I needed.  It does except it can't be based on anything non-deterministic (like getdate())

Comment: Does it have to be automated? Or - in other words - how is new data getting into the table (or existing data being updated)? Maybe it is easier to walk down this road? I also try to avoid using triggers and therefore re-route all DMLs through stored procedures and the stored procedure then writes into the table (or makes the requested changes). In your case I would have an SP like hr_update_PersonHun with as many parameters as you have columns in the table and an additional parameter called @action to find out if something should get inserted, deleted, or updated. Just a thought...